# How does thread context-switching work with global variable?

Tags: multithreading, context-switch

I have been confused at this question:
I have C++ function:

```
void withdraw(int x) {
     balance = balance - x;
}
```

`balance` is a global integer variable, which equals to `100` at the start.
We run the above function with two different thread: thread A and thread B. Thread A run `withdraw(50)` and thread B run `withdraw(30)`.

Assuming we don't protect `balance`, what is the final result of `balance` after running those threads in following sequences?

1. A1->A2->A3->B1->B2->B3
2. B1->B2->B3->A1->A2->A3
3. A1->A2->B1->B2->B3->A3
4. B1->B2->A1->A2->A3->B3

Explanation:

- A1 means OS execute the first line of function `withdraw` in thread A, A2 means OS execute the second line of function `withdraw` in thread A, B3 means OS execute the third line of function `withdraw` in thread B, and so on.
- The sequence is how OS schedule thread A & B presumably.

My answer is

1. 20
2. 20
3. 50 (Before context switch, OS saves `balance`. After context switch, OS restore `balance` to 50)
4. 70 (Similar to above)

But my friend disagrees, he said that `balance` was a global variable. Thus it is not saved in stack, so it does not affected by context switching. He claimed that all 4 sequences result in 20.

So who is right? I can't find fault in his logic.

(We assume we have one processor that can only execute one thread at a time)

Comment: What do you mean by line 1,2,3? The function has only one line

Comment: From what I understand, line 1 is `{`, line 2 is `balance = balance - x` line 3 is `}`.

Comment: Then I don't see the meaning of the question, because the decrement would happen "atomically" (if you only allow interruption between the lines ). A typical way to split this would be 1: Load if balance from memory 2:decrease value by X, 3: Store result back to balance.

Comment: This is last year final exam question, though. All answers here are kinda unexpected for me.

Comment: Two Possibilities: Either you didn't repeat the question exactly (like additional assumptions or preconditions that where stated in the question or something your supervisor said) or whoever wrote that exam didn't know how the c++ very well. Also be aware, that most/all answers are talking about possible behavior under ISO-c++-11 Standard. It might be possible for example that your code would not be undefined bahavior according to the POSIX standard, but I'm no expert there. Are you even sure, this is c++ Code and not e.g. Java?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line:

```
balance = balance - x;
```

Thread A reads balance. It is 100. Now, thread A subtracts 50 and ... oops

Thread B reads balance. It is 100. Now, thread B subtracts 30 and updates the variable, which is now 70.

...thread A continues now updates the variable, which is now 50. You've just lost the work that Thread B.

Threads don't execute "lines of code" -- they execute machine instructions. It does not matter if a global variable is affected by context switching. What matters is *when* the variable is read, and *when* it is written, by each thread, because the value is "taken off the shelf" and modified, then "put back". Once the first thread has read the global variable and is working with the value "somewhere in space", the second thread **must not** read the global variable until the first thread has written the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the threading standard you are using specifies, then there's no way to know. Most typical threading standards don't, so typically there's no way to know.

Your answer sounds like nonsense though. The OS has no idea what `balance` is nor any way to do anything to it around a context switch. Also, threads can run at the same time without context switches.

Your friend's answer also sounds like nonsense. How does he know that it won't be cached in a register by the compiler and thus some of the modifications will stomp on previous ones?

But the point is, both of you are just guessing about what might happen to happen. If you want to answer this usefully, you have to talk about what is guaranteed to happen.

Comment: If we have one processor which can execute only one thread at a time, isn't context-switch still necessary?

Comment: So even if we have can only execute one thread at a time, the result will still be unpredictable?

Comment: @acx_cosmos Yes, because (among other reasons) there's no rule that says a system with a single CPU must act differently from a system with multiple CPUs. You can't reason out a guarantee because you can't figure out any way it could go wrong, you only have guarantees if something assures it will go right.

Comment: But also, your assumption that values cached in registers will be written to main memory on a context switch is simply wrong. The registers are saved, which does you no good.

Comment: Could you clarify it a bit? Assuming one thread at a time, and it is scheduled like the third sequence. After we finish thread A, it's still possible that the result of thread A is not written to the main memory? I

Comment: @acx_cosmos Yes, because the thread might have stored it in a register and not gotten a chance to write it back to main memory yet. Or it could happen many other ways. You can't determine what will actually happen just by you not being able to think of a way it could happen differently. You only have the guarantees you actually have. Otherwise, you'll write code that will break with the next version of the CPU, compiler, OS, library, and so on, because they'll add new stuff that you didn't think of.

Comment: hi @David Schwartz +1 - I asked a question about this, could you explain to me how global variables are saved in a thread? THANKS IN ADVANCE  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390627/does-the-context-switch-retain-keep-state-of-variables-the-value-of-the-variab#comment133029662_75390627

Answer (score 0):

Clearly homework, but saved by doing actual work before asking.

First, forget about context switching. Context switching is totally irrelevant to the problem. Assume that you have multiple processors, each executing one thread, and each progressing at an unknown speed, stopping and starting at unpredictable times. Even better, assume that this stopping and storing is controlled by an enemy, who will try to break your program.

And because context switching is irrelevant, the OS will not save or restore anything. It won't touch the variable balance. Only your two threads will.

Your friend is absolutely, totally wrong. It's quite the opposite. Since balance is a global variable, both threads can read and write it. But you don't only have the problem that they might read and write it in unknown order, as you examined, it is worse. They could access it at the same time, and if one thread modifies data while another reads it, you have a race condition and anything at all could happen. Not only could you get *any* result, your program could also crash.

If balance was a local variable saved on the stack, then both threads would have each its own variable, and nothing bad would happen.

Comment: If we have one processor which can execute only one thread at a time, isn't context-switch still necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line:

```
balance = balance - x;
```

Thread A reads balance. It is 100. Now, thread A subtracts 50 and ... oops

Thread B reads balance. It is 100. Now, thread B subtracts 30 and updates the variable, which is now 70.

...thread A continues and updates the variable, which is now 50. You've just completely lost the work of Thread B.

Threads don't execute "lines of code" -- they execute machine instructions. It does not matter if a global variable is affected by context switching. What matters is *when* the variable is read, and *when* it is written, by each thread, because the value is "taken off the shelf" and modified, then "put back". Once the first thread has read the global variable and is working with the value "somewhere in space", the second thread cannot read the global variable until the first thread has written the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short answer for c++: Unsynchronized access to a shared variable is undefined behavior, so anything can happen. The value can e.g. be 100,70,50,20,42 or -458995. The program could crash or not. And in theory its even allowed to order pizza.

The actual machine code that is executed is usually far away from what your program looks like and in the case of undefined behavior, you are no longer guaranteed, that the actual behavior has anything to do with the c++ code you have written.

Comment: You means context-switching does not matter at all, as 4 sequences could result in anything, right?

Comment: Correct. The type of analysis you are performing would only make sense if balance would be of type `std::atomic <int>`.